# Smartcard ATR and select file command

Tags: java, python, smartcard, apdu

I just started to learn about smart cards a bit and I am using pyscard for practice.

So I have 2 questions (I am using visa prepaid card):

1) I saw on the internet that people said that there is a way to know which selection methods your card can use, by his ATR.
How can you determine that?
Can someone please show me an example.

2) I tried to select the MF of my visa card using a lot of techniques I saw on the internet. I tried with the aid, with the MF name and a lot of others and didn't get the result of `="90 00"`. Can someone please help me.

If you can also bring a good guide to learn from I would love that!

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use this site to decode your ATR: https://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/. Under the category indicator byte (0x80) you will see how applications can be selected.

2) Your card may have a different visa AID compared to other cards. Mostly used AID is  A0000000031010 which is visa debit or credit.

There are two ways to check what AID is supported by your card.

a) If you don't know the AID of the card you can try sending a payment system environment (PSE) AID. If the card supports PSE it will send back the list of AIDs supported. Check here how to send the select PSE: https://www.openscdp.org/scripts/tutorial/emv/applicationselection.html

Also check this question on PSE: [How to Read EMV based smart VISA card details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503783/how-to-read-emv-based-smart-visa-card-details)

b) Try sending all possible AIDs for VISA. Check this site for other Visa AIDs: http://emvfunctionalflow.blogspot.com/2018/05/visa-inc.html